# 2 decimal increment in seq makes everything with 2 decimal

Tags: bash, python, python3, seq

I want to use this command in bash:

```
datarange=$(seq 0.5 0.25 5.5)
```

with output

```
echo $datarange = 0.50 0.75 1.00 1.25 1.50 1.75 2.00 2.25 2.50 2.75 3.00 3.25 3.50 3.75 4.00 4.25 4.50 4.75 5.00 5.25 5.50
```

The problem is that this is for going into directories labeled D$i in a for loop where $datarange is called, but also where it's going to be for a qsub file it calls certain files numbered after a python numpy arange like this one:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> Steps=np.arange(0.5,5.75,0.25)
>>> print(Steps)
[0.5  0.75 1.   1.25 1.5  1.75 2.   2.25 2.5  2.75 3.   3.25 3.5  3.75
 4.   4.25 4.5  4.75 5.   5.25 5.5 ]
```

As the name needs a str I write this in Python

```
filenamelist=[filenamer+str(Steps[j])+'.fdf' for j in range(len(Steps))]
```

resulting in a file name like this one for example in the 2nd element (in python counting, whereas it's the 3rd one):

```
filenamer1.0.fdf
```

whereas for the 3rd (4th) would be:

```
filenamer1.5.fdf
```

and the next one:

```
filenamer1.75.fdf
```

As I need the D$i to be the same of the NumPy arange data, how can make that possible? If I use seq -f %.3g, it only keeps me the three more significant decimals but without adding a decimal. If I use seq -f %.3f, it would be the same result that if I won't use anything at all.

May I need to stick to Python to change the directory and call over the program or is it solvable in Bash?

EDIT: to clarify, i need help to do it in Bash
And I dont want to elliminate all trailing zeros using %g because for example as you see in Python arange 1. and such stay in the strings as 1.0 and such, and so i can't read the files properly.

Comment: Please clarify your question: do you want help with your Bash or your Python code?

Comment: At least with the GNU Coreutils implementation, the format specifier `%g` (with no explicit precision) appears to remove trailing zeros

Comment: Why don't you keep your convoluted post simple by just stating this is my input and that is my expected output. It's hard to follow what you're wanting to convey

Comment: `datarange=$( seq 0.5 0.25 5.5 | sed 's/0$//' )` or one at a time in any POSIX shell, which includes bash: `for v in $( seq 0.5 0.25 5.5 ); do ... ${v%0} ... done`

Comment: @spuck edited and uploaded

Comment: @steeldriver edited regarding i dont want to erase all trailing zeros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want the output of `LC_ALL=C seq -f %.15g 0.5 0.25 5.5`, but with a `.` appended (or possibly `.0`, it's not clear to me from your question) where a dot is missing, so:

```
datarange=$(
  LC_ALL=C seq -f %.15g 0.5 0.25 5.5 |
    sed '/\./!s/$/./'
)
```

(or `sed '/\./!s/$/.0/'` to append `.0`)

Here, using:

- `%.15g` instead of `%.3g` or `%g` (same as `%.6g`) to avoid the risk of numbers over `1000` (for `%.3g`) or `1000000` (for `%g`) being output as `1e+03`/`1e+06`
- `LC_ALL=C` for the decimal radix character to be always `.` (and not `,`) regardless of the locale of the user.

In any case, inside `$datarange`, the numbers will be separated by newline characters, the reason why you see them space-separated in the output of `echo $datarange` is because you forgot to quote that `$datarange`, so split+glob was applied to it, and the newline character happens to be in the default value of `$IFS`, so the individual numbers were passed as separate arguments to `echo` which it outputs space-separated.

If you wanted to store a space separated list in `$datarange`, you'd need to pipe the output of `sed` to `paste -sd ' ' -`, and if you wanted to store those numbers as separate elements of a `bash` *array* variable, you'd use:

```
readarray -t datarange < <(
  LC_ALL=C seq -f %.15g 0.5 0.25 5.5 |
    sed '/\./!s/$/./'
)
```

And use `cmd "${datarange[@]}"` to pass those elements as separate arguments to `cmd`, or `"${datarange[*]}"` to join those elements with the first character of `$IFS` (space by default).

Comment: This is almost exactly what i was looking for.: If I append a ".0" where it's missing and I use %g formatting, it shows what I want. THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Comment: However I am encountering the following errors:when incluiding this command inside a .sh file in order to run it on a PBS cluster via qsub. -bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
/bin/bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8)
/bin/sh: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_US.utf-8). I have no sudo privileges in the cluster.

Comment: Also I have to say that the language of the cluster is LANG=es_ES.UTF-8. Does it have something to do?

Comment: Use `LC_ALL=C` (or `LC_ALL=POSIX`) which is guaranteed to work and have `.` as the decimal radix character. Any other locale is not guaranteed to be present on a given system. Run `locale -a` to see the list of available locale. In any case `LC_ALL=C seq...` only sets the locale for that very invocation of the `seq` command (it's roughly equivalent to disabling localisation for that command invocation)

Comment: In Spanish, the decimal radix character is `,`, so I'd expect that without `LC_ALL=C seq...`, `seq` would output `0,5`, `0,75`... What matters here is the `LC_NUMERIC` setting in the `locale` output. See also the output of `locale decimal_point`

Comment: It seems now it works. I used LC_ALL="POSIX" inside the .sh file and now there is no problem. Thank you! Also the decimal point is a point and not a comma